# How to programmatically maintain umask in /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am looking for a way to programmatically maintain a consistent umask in the files `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`.  They have an entry such as follows:

```
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
  umask 002
else
  umask 022
fi
```

So I would like to programmatically check for the first `if` statement above.  If found, check to verify the next line is a umask (and not a comment) and if so, set it back to my standard umask if it has deviated from it.  I realize I could just copy the entire file but would rather not disturb other changes that may have been made.  I'm sure someone has done with with sed/awk/grep and can share or perhaps have thoughts on how to achieve this?  I am required to maintain a umask for the login shell and for the non-login shell.  It references this at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/assembly_managing-the-umask_configuring-basic-system-settings. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered putting your customizations in `/etc/profile.d` so that they are not overwritten by changes to `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and explain _why_ you want this. The normal way for this sort of thing is to edit your own personal `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.profile` files or, if you want it to be applied to new users as well, to change the files in `/etc/skel`. If you explain what your final objective is, we should be able to give a better solution (messing with the standard files in `/etc` is very rarely the right approach).

Comment: To address your request, I just added the following to my question "I am required to maintain a umask for the login shell and for the non-login shell.  It references this at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/assembly_managing-the-umask_configuring-basic-system-settings."  So its something I am required to do.  Hope this helps.

Comment: For what user? All users? All non-system users? Your user? New users? I am guessing it will be for all non-system users based on the code you show, but it would help to be sure. The details will depend on that. In any case, the solution will be to either use files inside `/etc/profile.d` or user-specific ones in the relevant user's $HOME directories.

Comment: For all users.  Please reference the Red Hat doc I quoted re the files to do this in which shows /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc.  I'm looking for a way to do as they show only programmatically.

Comment: You want to parse the startup scripts to check if they have changed your umask from its default and it change it to the default only if it has been changed? Why not just set the umask?

Comment: @terdon, there is in RedHat/CentOS.

Comment: @ilkkachu oh snap! Of course there is! Thanks, I keep forgetting, it's been years since I last used an RH system.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to understand why this could make any sense (see comments), but your task can be done like this:

```
sed -i".bak" '\_if \[ $UID -gt 199 ] && \[ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then_,/^[^#]*else/s/^\([^#]*umask\).*/\1 002/' /etc/profile /etc/bashrc
```

The address range covers all lines between your `if` clause and the next not-comment `else`. In this line a not-comment `umask` is changed to `002`.

Note that you need to escape the `[` and that I did choose the underscore as delimiter for the first address to avoid escaping all slashes.

If really somebody/something is changing those files, you might consider using a more flexible pattern for the `if` line; otherwise changing the `if` line along with the `umask` line will break the script. Maybe

```
sed -i".bak" '/if.*$UID *-gt *199/,/^[^#]*else/s/^\([^#]*umask\).*/\1 002/' /etc/profile /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is VERY close but unfortunately, it duplicates the umask entry as in the following example:
  umask 002 002
I hope I'll be able to figure it out but as always, assistance/ideas welcome!

Comment: Stupid me! I corrected it.

Comment: Why is there an escaped undesrcore in `sed -i".bak" '\_if ...`? Typo?

Comment: @terdon As written, to use the underscore as delimiter for the address pattern. From the `man`: *In a context address, the construction "\cBREc", where c is any character other than <backslash> or <newline>, shall be identical to "/BRE/". If the character designated by c appears following a <backslash>, then it shall be considered to be that literal character, which shall not terminate the BRE. For example, in the context address "\xabc\xdefx", the second x stands for itself, so that the BRE is "abcxdef".*

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to programmatically maintain a consistent umask in the files `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`. They have an entry such as follows:

```bsh
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
  umask 002
else
  umask 022
fi
```

> I would like to programmatically check for the first `if` statement above. If found, check to verify the next line is a umask (and not a comment) and if so, set it back to my standard umask if it has deviated from it.

Why would comments appear in the middle of the `if` command? There are none in your example. You can simplify this process greatly by **having the code identically formatted** anywhere you need to check for its presence. If you can do that, here's a Python script that will do what you're asking. Make sure the code text between the triple quotes is **exactly** the same at is appears in the files you want to check (although in this case it really doesn't cause any problems if the code appears more than once in a script):

```py
snippet = '''
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
  umask 002
else
  umask 022
fi
'''
with open('/etc/profile','r+') as f:
    if snippet not in f.read():
        f.write(snippet)
with open('/etc/bashrc','r+') as f:
    if snippet not in f.read():
        f.write(snippet)
```

Because the write locations are root-owned you would need to use `sudo` when invoking the script: **`sudo python myscript.py`** or **`sudo python3 myscript.py`**. The script checks if `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile` contain the block of text defined in `snippet` and if not it is appended to the file(s).

### Is this even worth doing?

Since you express concerns that the content of `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile` might get changed I have to wonder who you think would be doing those changes. If it's the system itself, well the umask values you want to use are the defaults anyway so I can't see the system changing those to anything else. On the other hand, if you've got a gremlin or another `sudoer` who fiddles with those files...

It's important to realize that a test which tells you the code text is already in the script tells you nothing about whether that code will be executed. It's **very easy** to make some *subtle* changes that will **make your code not execute** despite it being in the script.

Here's one where the code only executes if `false = true` (i.e., never):

```bsh
if false; then

if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
  umask 002
else
  umask 022
fi

fi
```

This one wraps the code in a HEREDOC string which is never called.

```bsh
: <<'no-umask-4u'

if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
  umask 002
else
  umask 022
fi

no-umask-4u
```

This one simply changes the umask after your code executes (very simple example here):

```bsh
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
  umask 002
else
  umask 022
fi

umask 077
```

Now what? In all of the above scenarios any programmatic test for the presence of your code text in the scripts will pass even though the code will never actually be executed (or in the case of the last one it executes but is subsequently overridden).

> I realize I could just copy the entire file but would rather not disturb other changes that may have been made.

Generating a sha1 hash of the file and checking to see if it ever changes might be worth considering (it would certainly be more robust than a simple check if the code is in the file somewhere). I am curious what would be the source of the "other changes" you're concerned about.

Comment: "Why would comments appear in the middle of the if command?" -- Because the line with `umask` can be commented out. And anyway, who knows where someone might add comments.

Comment: @ilkkachu Sure, anything can be commented out. I still don't know what would be the source of those comments becoming inserted into the command after the file was saved. The system sure wouldn't do it and I assume OP doesn't enter fugue states, which means there must be other sudoers potentially doing goofy things.